# How do you get pygame to continue to run/look for user input while in the background

Tags: pygame, background, running-other-programs

I’m looking to make my game work In the background and if WASD is clicked to move the character on the screen regardless if the window for the program is selected or not. To better clarify I’m looking to use an application and simultaneously have my game update the players location if the other application clicks the buttons W,A,S, or D.

Comment: You can use other libraries which dont need an window and if needed use a pygame window at the same time.

Comment: The libraries `pynput` and `keyboard` might help you. A pygame window can't detect keys when it's not selected.

Comment: thanks jerry I have uploaded what I came up with but cant get out the bugs if you had any input.                                                                                                                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333872/can-any-one-tell-me-why-no-matter-what-i-do-i-cant-get-the-dot-to-move

Answer (score 0):

You can use **keyboard** for it:

```
pip install keyboard

import keyboard
# This will detect q key press.
# And returns True/False.
# You need to put this code inside you game loop.
keyboard.is_pressed('q')
```